# Is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

**Commemorative wines for a particular movie?**

Not long ago, I read this article ([Francis Ford Winery unveils Wines to be poured at 2017 Academy Awards® Ceremony & Governors Ball](https://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/89th-gb-francis-ford-coppola-wines.pdf)) and it got me thinking if there exists a wine that commemorates and could be paired with a particular movie?

Pairing beer with a particular movie is quite commonplace, but commemorative wines that could be paired to a particular movie is much more rare.

Here is a beer example of what I am trying to convey: [The Hobbit Series of Beers ships this week, coming very soon.](http://beerpulse.com/2014/08/the-hobbit-series-of-beers-ships-this-week-coming-very-soon-3434/)

[image: The Hobbit Gollum Precious]

> [Gollum Precious Pils](http://beerpulse.com/beer/the-hobbit-gollum-precious-pils/): A strong Imperial Pils, with flavors as smooth and crafty as Gollum himself. Like the ring which Gollum pursued for the rest of his life, his “precious” pils, if your quest leads you to it, could extend your life too! (at least we’d like to think so) It will, at a minimum, make your journey a little more enjoyable!

Answer (score 3):

It looks on topic to me and will post on main, thus opening up another category if you all do not mind.

Comment: yea go ahead and post it seems like it should be fine as long as it does not just generate a load of list answers but i cant see anything wrong with giving it ago

Comment: Nice to see you back @Jamie Eltringham